# Reading different lines of a text file batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, text-files

If I have a text file call text.txt and I have this code to read it.

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type text.txt') do ( 
    set "Var=%%x"
    ECHO !Var!
)
pause
```

How could I only display the third line of the text file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

for /f "usebackq skip=2 delims=" %%x in ("text.txt") do echo %%x & goto done
:done
pause
```

Skip two lines, write the third and exit the for loop